# How do you use a smartcard to log in to Windows from a linux box?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, smartcard

I'm using CentOS 5.3 and I want to use the Terminal Server Client to remote log in to a WindowsXP machine that uses smartcards exclusively to access the domain accounts.

How can I set up the Terminal Server Client to use the coolkey pkcs11 library to log in to a Windows machine?  Or is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

newer versions of the "[rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/)" utility have the ability to pass on a smart card to the remote windows machine, using the "-scard" switch.
You'll of course need you reader and smartcard to be accessible/readable by the linux machine you're connecting from. There is a lot of information on the subject on the [pcsc](http://www.linuxnet.com/) (look under software) and the [openct](http://www.opensc-project.org/openct/) project pages.

As for CentOS 5.3 specifics. The coolkey pkcs11 library supports a pretty small subset of smart cards. I believe CentOS 5.3 comes with pcsc, but not openct. As for rdesktop, it comes with a pretty outdated version, I suggest you upgrade.

Good luck, and keep us posted.

Comment: I downloaded rdesktop 1.6 and when I compiled it the smartcard support, it had a link problem.  I haven't looked into it further yet.